# Block access to certain .mp3 files in PHP

Tags: php, mp3

I want to allow only registered user's to download a .mp3 file.

So, I decided to hide the actual location of the .mp3 file and allow downloads using http://example.com/donwload.php?mp3_name=1

The File donwload.php checks weather the user is logged in and then uses readfile() to read the file location in a folder that is not shown the the user.

The problem here is that, accessing http://example.com/donwload.php?mp3_name=1 for a .mp3 file of 500kb takes 3 seconds to load (the save dialog box to appear)

Is there any other way to do so or read files quickly in PHP?

Thanks
Akash

Comment: Please provide some sample code so that we can see what your PHP script is doing.

Comment: How can you be sure that the delay is caused by your PHP script and not your browser/location?  You might need to run a few benchmarks before you can be 100% sure that PHP is to blame.  It might be a server hardware issue (out of your hands) or a local software issue (out of your hands for other users).

Comment: the readfile() function takes 3 seconds to completely read the .mp3 file, tested using microtime() functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really short answer, as I'm running out. (Will provide more information later). This answer also takes an alterntive approach to what you are trying to do.

If possible you should use a system that has a dedicated ACL backing all of the files which are stored on it. 
For instance, if you go with Amazon S3, then you can provide your own ACL for each object that is stored within a bucket, and you can also generate links on the fly that are valid and signed for only X number of minutes.

Given your scenario, what you could do is store every MP3 file that you have on something like Amazon S3 (There are others out there so don't feel like you have to use S3), and then when a user makes a purchase and the transaction is confirmed, you can use the S3 API to generate a link for the image.

It would be something like :

`get_object_url( 'my-mp3s.com', 'albums/Foo/bar.mpg')`

You will then get a URL which you can provide to the customer. 
Alternatively, you can ask Amazon to generate a URL that expired within 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use file_get_contents instead of readfile() http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

or the X-Sendfile apache module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your mp3 on a different server you could install lighttpd with modsecdownload or run lighttpd on a different port if you have only one machine only

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModSecDownload

so you than you could generate only for logged in users a download link, which is valid for few mins - hours, and they can download it. I think this is better, cause it will use less memory than reading the file and sending it to the user, if you have much traffic.

Hope this helps!